# Add entries to Info.plist in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, info.plist

In Qt, [it is possible](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_do_i_add_a_custom_info.plist_to_my_mac_application_with_qmake) to specify an `Info.plist` file to use when building on Mac, as follows:

```
QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = MyInfo.plist
```

This replaces the Qt auto-generated `Info.plist` file with another one.

Rather than replace Qt's auto generated one entirely, is it possible to add individual entries?

I don't think it will make little practical difference but I'd like to be able to do it because I feel it would be "tidier" to just add the additional items I want rather than brutally replace the whole file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible. But Qt makes your life easier with some variables that you can use in `plist` file. From Qt documentation:

> In the .plist file, you can define some variables, e.g., @EXECUTABLE@,
>   which qmake will replace with the actual executable name. Other
>   variables include @ICON@, @TYPEINFO@, @LIBRARY@, and @SHORT_VERSION@.

Answer (score 4):

Find a file named 'Info.list.app'. This is the template of Info.list. You can use it as a start point and append you own entries. It is typically location like Qt5.7.0/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/Info.plist.app in your QT root dir.

See [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-info-plist) for more detail.